# numpy.max vs builtin max

Tags: python, numpy

What are the differences between `numpy.max` and `max`?  My understanding is that the main advantage of working with `numpy.max` is that it can handle multidimensional arrays, however they behave differently in the following:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: max([1, float('nan')])
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: max([float('nan'), 1])
Out[3]: nan

In [4]: np.max([1, float('nan')])
Out[4]: nan

In [5]: np.max([float('nan'), 1])
Out[5]: nan
```

This suggests that `numpy.max` and `max` treat the basic idea of "maximum" differently, at least in some edge cases such as this. Is there a reason why the two functions take different conventions, and in particular, why the behavior of `max` depends on the ordering?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of other differences between the two? Or specifically why the `nan` case is handled the way it is? I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: You might want to check `np.nanmax` if you want to get the highest non-NaN value.

Comment: I'm just curious about the two functions take different conventions, and why `max` has this odd order-dependent behavior.  Have updated question to reflect this.

Comment: My guess is `max` simply loops and update if `value > current_max`, since both `1>nan` and `nan>1` are false, he simply keeps the first element. `np.max` is "conceptually more correct" imo, since you don't really know what is the max between a number and something that's not a number. I guess since numpy is specialized in numerical computation (unlike python core library), they are more careful about this kind of limit case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nan` is not comparable; the following all return `False`:

- `1 < float('nan')`
- `1 > float('nan')`
- `float('nan') < 1`
- `float('nan') > 1`

The behavior of `max` can be explained if you assume that it works as follows: assume the first element in the list is the largest, compare the current largest to the next element in the list, and take the next element if `next > current`. Since a comparison to `float('nan')` always returns `False`, `max` will think it is the largest element if it is the left-hand operand of the comparison, but the smallest if it is the right-hand operand.

The behavior of `np.max` seems to correctly handle `nan` by returning it for *any* operation that involves `nan`. That is, `nan` would not only be the maximum of any list, but also the minimum, or the median, or the sum, or the product, etc.